# What is going wrong with this sed command

Tags: bash, sed

I have to transform first occurrence of word 'the' and replace it with 'this' in each line of input text, case sensitive search and replace.

Following is my command to do the task but it is going wrong

> sed 's/\Wthe\W/this/'

The problem I found was similar to this simulated case :

Input-text : **as the word**

Output-text(correct) : **as that word**

Output-text : **asthatword** (what the command is producing).

Comment: Why not just `sed 's/the/that/'` that will replace all the occurrences of `the` but you can work from there

Comment: `\W` is not part of BRE or ERE, which are the two forms of regular expressions sed supports.

Comment: I have tried that but it what happens is suppose text is : 'there" then the output is : 'thatre' i.e. `the(replaced by that)+re`

Comment: Try `sed 's/ the / this /'`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I got them from here http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-10a

Comment: @Creator, that link **explicitly says** that `\W` isn't portable. Look for the part about "regex syntax clashes".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\W` is [PCRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions), not [BRE or ERE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended). It is thus not supported in standard `sed`.

```
sed 's/(^|[[:space:]])the([[:space:]]|$)/\1this\2/'
```

In `^|[[:space:]]`, `^` matches the beginning of the line; `[[:space:]]` matches any whitespace character class. Putting this inside of parenthesis creates a matching group which can be referred to later with `\1` (since this is the first such group).

`[[:space:]]|$` does the same, but with `$` indicating end-of-line.

---

That said -- if you're targeting only GNU sed, and not POSIX sed, you might instead consider:

```
sed 's/\<the\>/this/'
```

Comment: can you please add refrences to PCRE / BRE and ERE

Comment: BRE and ERE are documented at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap09.html

Comment: For PCRE, the wikipedia article isn't a bad place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions

Comment: Consider `echo 'as the' | sed 's/[[:space:]]the[[:space:]]/this/' ` The `the` at the end of the line is not replaced...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended covers BRE and ERE, and has a section following it on Perl's syntax, though the dedicated PCRE article Charles linked is better for that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - Please add an explanation for the command, I am quite a newbie for sed and I am still confused with working of your solution.

Comment: Okay but what is problem in this  this `sed 's/[[:space:]]the[[:space:]]/ this /'`

Comment: @Creator, the problem with that is that it wouldn't work at the very beginning or end of a line (not starting or ending with a space), because it would be looking for a space before or after it.

Comment: @Creator in case you didn't realise- this command would fail if a word was followed or preceded by anything that's not a space, e.g. in `"the dog."` neither word would be identified since `the` is preceded by `"`, not a start-of-string (`^`) or space (`[[:space:]]`), and `dog` is succeded by `.`. Is that a problem??

Comment: If it were, one might consider `[^[:alnum:]]` instead of `[[:space:]]`.

Comment: Or maybe `[^[:alpha:]]`? idk, depends what his input really looks like. It might be just fine as-is.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to capture the non-word surrounding word `the` and then use back-reference in replacement:

```
s='as the word'
sed 's/\(\W\)the\(\W\)/\1this\2/' <<< "$s"
as this word
```

or better to use word boundary:

```
sed 's/\bthe\b/this/' <<< "$s"
as this word
```

Comment: You have a `sed` that honors `\W` at all? I can't reproduce this working.

Comment: That was gnu-sed 4.2.2 installed via `home bew` on my OSX

Comment: Ahh. My negative result is from BSD sed.

Comment: My default `sed` does honor `\W` but really `\b` is the better answer since you have beginning and end of line to consider...

Comment: @dawg: Yes I agree `sed 's/\bthe\b/this/'` is better command here

Answer (score 0):

you are replacing the non-word-characters (blanks in this case) as well. An easy way round is

```
sed 's/\Wthe\W/ that /'
```

or

```
sed 's/\(\W\)the\(\W\)/\1that\2/'
```

to keep the original non-word-characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you're using `\W` to make this a whole word search and replace. Try using `\b` to set word boundaries instead:

```
sed 's/\bthe\b/this/'
```